# How can I put Random images without repeating them?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried to program an app in which some cards appear, and it is necessary to join them with other cards, the problem is that when I randomize them, some are repeated and, others, do not appear.

How can I make the images appear Random but not repeat?

Here's how I'm doing it

```
  int[] images = {R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four};
     Random rand = new Random();
     imgSelected.setImageResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);
      imgSelected2.setImageResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);
       imgSelected3.setImageResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);
        imgSelected4.setImageResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);

 int[] images2 = {R.id.imgfive, R.id.imgsix, R.id.imgseven, R.id.imgeight};

    //
                 Random rand2 = new Random();
    img1.setImageResource(images2[rand2.nextInt(images2.length)]);
    img2.setImageResource(images2[rand2.nextInt(images2.length)]);
    img3.setImageResource(images2[rand2.nextInt(images2.length)]);
    img4.setImageResource(images2[rand2.nextInt(images2.length)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collections.shuffle()` to get a random permutation of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the image as you use them.

```
List<Integer> images....
Random rand = new Random;
int randomInt = rand.nextInt(images.size());
imgSelected.setImageResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);
images.remove(randomInt);
randomInt = rand.nextInt(images.size());
imgSelected2.setImageResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);
images.remove(randomInt);
randomInt = rand.nextInt(images.size());
imgSelected3.setImageResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);
images.remove(randomInt);
randomInt = rand.nextInt(images.size());
imgSelected4.setImageResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);
images.remove(randomInt);
```

This way the image isn't there to be used a second time.